# jQuery add active class to link in submenu from main menu on click

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to to add an active class to a submenu (subnav) item when an item
in the main navigation is clicked. The goal is to highlight the submenu item when
the main menu item is clicked. The submenu items are links to sections of a page:

```
<div id="subnav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#adaptivetech">Adaptive Technology</a></li>
    <li><a href="#iepspecialed">IEP and Special Ed Forms</a></li>
    <li><a href="#behaviorplanning">Behavior Planning Forms</a></li>
    <li><a href="#npsnpainfo">NPS/NPA Information and Forms</a></li>
    <li><a href="#privateschoolref">Private School Referral for Assessment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#programtransfer">Program Transfer</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is what the main menu looks like:

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
    <li><a href="newselpasite3.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Meetings/Workshops</a>
     <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Selpa Workshops</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Selpa Committee Meeting for 2012-2013</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Archived Agendas and Minutes</a></li>
              </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="top_parent">Services</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Adaptive Technology Center</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Alternative Dispute Resolution</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Autism Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">BEST Schoolwide Positive Behavior Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Community Advisory Committee</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Early Start Infant Program</a></li>
              </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Forms</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#adaptivetech">Adaptive Technology</a></li>
      <li><a href="#iepspecialed">All IEP and Special Education Forms</a></li>
       <li><a href="#behaviorplanning">Behavior Planning Forms</a></li>
       <li><a href="#npsnpainfo">NPS/NPA Information and Forms</a></li>
       <li><a href="#privateschoolref">Private School Referral for Assessment</a></li>
       <li><a href="#programtransfer">Program Transfer</a></li>
    </ul></li>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What difficulties do you have with this ? Can't regular 'click' event handling solve this ?

Comment: looks like your markup is missing the ending main menu ul tag

Comment: Sorry, I truncated the list and accidentally dropped off the closing ul tag

Comment: If each of the sections were a separate page I would just manually add the active class to the corresponding page. Because they are all on the same page I need a way to dynamically add the classes. My experience with jQuery/Javascript is quite limited

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QTYQD/)

```
$('ul li ul').find('li a').click(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     $('a').removeClass('active');
     $this.addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: This seems to highlight the list item in the main menu when I click it, not the corresponding item in the subnav menu.

Comment: What is seems to come down to is that I need a way to select the href element in the subnav menu that matches the href element that is clicked on in the top level menu

Comment: Hi Jai- Thanks for your answer but it seems like your code adds the active class to the item that is clicked on. I actually want the active class added to the an item in a second list when an item in the first list is clicked on. The items in the two lists have matching hrefs.

Comment: Could you use something like this to get the href string for the main menu list item:                                                     var urlString = ("ul.sf-menu li li a").get(window.location.pathname);

Answer (score 0):

Try following.

```
$('li').each(function(){
    if(window.location.href.indexOf($(this).find('a:first').attr('href'))>-1)
    {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```